# Rails Multi Table Inheritance and Polymorphic Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

I'm currently developing an application using Rails 3.2 and have run into a bit of a problem. I know this has been asked hundreds of times before but I couldn't find an answer that solved it. Here is a similar ER: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5V0G.png

Fairly obvious what i'm trying to do. I'm hoping for the association to read like the following:

```ruby
Supplier.first.theatres.first.events.first.orders
TourEvent.first.orders
Tour.first.orders
```

Now it would be nice to be able to define my models like so:

```ruby
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  belongs_to :eventable, polymorphic: true

  # id, eventable_id, eventable_type, title, date, price
end

class TourEvent < Event
  belongs_to :tour

  # id, tour_id, rendezvous, guide_name
end

class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :events, class_name: 'TourEvent'

  # id, name, venue, duration
end
```

But I understand that's reserved for "STI" rather than "MTI". Any ideas how to get my solution working without the need for complicated mixins or plugins? Or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make something like this:

```
suppliers 
has_many :events

events
belongs_to :suppliers
belongs_to :institutions
has_many :orders
# id, supplier_id, institution_id, ...

institutions
# id, type, title, ...
types: theatre, club, tour

orders
belongs_to :events
# id, event_id
```

Then, you can access to event orders:

```
Supplier.first.events.first.orders
```

Comment: Sorry - I don't think you understand the problem. I've done some further reading and I believe I'm right by saying it's currently not possible to do Multiple-Table-Inheritance natively in Rails 3.2.1 (yet!). Would be a nice addition.

Comment: As I see in picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/x5V0G.png you want to store in DB suppliers, orders and events. Event belongs to institution (such as theather or club). Why you need additional tables such theather_events or club_events? Why you need table for each institution?

Comment: each 'institution' stores different information. It's important for me to distinguish that.

Comment: Your institution table would be STI. You can create models for each type of institution.